# Change getdata to CURL or web address

Tags: php, magento

I have the following script that does wonders for my stock update, however I would love this to work from a remote URL without sharing access to the main Magento server.

Script here:

```
<?php

$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app('admin');
Mage::register('isSecureArea', 1);
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','1024M');
function _getConnection($type = 'core_read'){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection($type);
}

function _getTableName($tableName){
    return Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getTableName($tableName);
}

function _getAttributeId($attribute_code = 'price'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql = "SELECT attribute_id
                FROM " . _getTableName('eav_attribute') . "
            WHERE
                entity_type_id = ?
                AND attribute_code = ?";
    $entity_type_id = _getEntityTypeId();
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_id, $attribute_code));
}

function _getEntityTypeId($entity_type_code = 'catalog_product'){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_type_id FROM " . _getTableName('eav_entity_type') . " WHERE entity_type_code = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($entity_type_code));
}

function _checkIfSkuExists($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_no FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    $count      = $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
    if($count > 0){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}

function _getIdFromSku($sku){
    $connection = _getConnection('core_read');
    $sql        = "SELECT entity_id FROM " . _getTableName('catalog_product_entity') . " WHERE sku = ?";
    return $connection->fetchOne($sql, array($sku));
}

function _updateStocks($data){
    $connection     = _getConnection('core_write');
    $sku            = $data[0];
    $newQty         = $data[1];
    $productId      = _getIdFromSku($sku);
    $attributeId    = _getAttributeId();

    $sql            = "UPDATE " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_item') . " csi,
                       " . _getTableName('cataloginventory_stock_status') . " css
                       SET
                       csi.qty = ?,
                       csi.is_in_stock = ?,
                       css.qty = ?,
                       css.stock_status = ?
                       WHERE
                       csi.product_id = ?
                       AND csi.product_id = css.product_id";
    $isInStock      = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $stockStatus    = $newQty > 0 ? 1 : 0;
    $connection->query($sql, array($newQty, $isInStock, $newQty, $stockStatus, $productId));
}
/***************** UTILITY FUNCTIONS ********************/

$csv                = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data               = $csv->getData('/var/www/html/var/import/updateStockLevels.csv'); //path to csv
array_shift($data);

$message = '';
$count   = 1;
foreach($data as $_data){
    if(_checkIfSkuExists($_data[0])){
        try{
            _updateStocks($_data);
            $message .= $count . '> Success:: Qty (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') has been updated. <br />';

        }catch(Exception $e){
            $message .=  $count .'> Error:: while Upating  Qty (' . $_data[1] . ') of Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') => '.$e->getMessage().'<br />';
        }
    }else{
        $message .=  $count .'> Error:: Product with Sku (' . $_data[0] . ') does\'t exist.<br />';
    }
    $count++;
}
echo $message;

?>
```

Can this be changed to pull the file from CURL or something like that as a fixed URL from where to retrieve the CSV file? Some expert help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Comment: [link]https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26348007/php-get-csv-from-url-load-into-array-format

Comment: Thank you @Jamie_D - but how can I implement this into my current script?

Comment: See updated answer

Comment: Technically, you really should extend Magento's  **Varien_File_Csv** class and override the **getData** function, but that would be out of the scope of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by replacing the following lines in your utility functions:

```
$csv = new Varien_File_Csv();
$data = $csv->getData('/var/www/html/var/import/updateStockLevels.csv');
array_shift($data);
```

With:

```
$csvData = "http://www.yoururl.com/updateStockLevels.csv";
$fileData = fopen($csvData,'r');
while (($line = fgetcsv($fileData)) !== FALSE) {
    $data[] = $line;
}
array_shift($data);
```

Comment: Thank you - but getting: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Notice: Undefined variable: file in /var/www/html/stockimport.php on line 86' in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php:245 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/stockimport.php(86): mageCoreErrorHandler(8, 'Undefined varia...', '/var/www/html/s...', 86, Array) #1 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Core/functions.php on line 245

Comment: Sorry about that ... see updated answer ... should be `$fileData = fopen($csvData,'r');`

Comment: @David Good to hear!